# Having trouble changing opacity when hovering over a floated div

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I've made a JS Fiddle here which is working correctly, however it is not workingin my development site.

http://jsfiddle.net/yr7rmho0/

Site is running Wordpress, and the link above contains a condensed version of what's on my site.

Basically, I have a Wordpress sidebar item, wrapped in `<li>` tags. I am adding a class to this tag to make it float int he bottom left hand corner when scrolled.

I want to set the opacity to .25 in the CSS, and make it appear full opacity when hovered. My problem is, that on the development site, when hovering, no opacity changes are being made. The div is the most upper layer, as I can click and interact with it.

```
$('#request-consultation.fixed-bottom-left').hover(
    function() { $( this ).fadeTo( 'fast', '1'); },
    function() { $( this ).fadeTo( 'slow', '.25'); }
);
```

I don't understand why it's not working on the site, but it is in JS Fiddle?

UPDATE:

I've noticed that if I change the code above to just be the ID, it works okay, but it also affects when the sidebar element is not floated (I've got a script that adds the fixed-bottom-left class when scrolled). If I use the class, nothing happens.

**So, the ID of the widget works, and the class of `widget-container` works on all the sidebar widgets. But if I just choose `fixed-bottom-left` as a class on it's own, nothing happens. I believe it's this class that's the issue. But why?**

Comment: Have you tried emptying your browsers cache?

Comment: Try replacing all instances of `$` with `jQuery`, Wordpress uses jQuery [no conflict mode](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/) by default.

Comment: It's not that, I've got loads of other jQuery scripts inside my init.js file, all running fine. Everything is wrapped using a no conflict wrapper, so `$` can be used.

Comment: Shouldn't the opacity be a `Number`, rather than a `String`? Or does jQuery not care nowadays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use CSS?

```
#request-consultation.fixed-bottom-left {
    opacity:.25;
    transition:all 0.3s linear;
}
#request-consultation.fixed-bottom-left:hover{
    opacity:1;
    transition:all 1s linear;
}
```

**UPDATE**
For older browser

```
#request-consultation.fixed-bottom-left {
    opacity:.25;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
#request-consultation.fixed-bottom-left:hover{
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 1s linear;
    -o-transition: all 1s linear;
    transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

Comment: Make sure to additionally add the `-webkit` prefix, if you want to support some older browsers.

Comment: This is the answer. Stupidly, I didn't think about using CSS at all, which is what I usually always try to do!. Thanks very much. Still, would be nice to know why jQuery wasn't affecting that one CSS class!

Comment: @Lee try to check it with 'console.log($(this))' at hover, '$('.fixed-bottom-left').length' or try to find it with $(document.body).find('.fixed-bottom-left')